# Most frequent in aggregated function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function defined like below:

```
def process_trans(chunk):
    grouped_object=chunk.groupby('msno',sort=False) # not sorting results in a minor speedup
    func = {
        'late_count':['sum'],
        'is_discount':['count'],
        'is_not_discount':['count'],
        'discount':['sum'], 'is_auto_renew':['mean'], 'is_cancel':['mean'], 'payment_type' : ['??'}
    result=grouped_object.agg(func)
    return result
```

As you can see, I know that I can insert `sum`, `count`, `mean` for each column. What type of keyword I can insert for determine the `payment_type` that appear most frequently. Note that each type is represented by integer.

I see people are introducing `mode` but the index 0 is needed to identify the most frequent item. Any better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and select first value of `index`, because function return sorted `Series`:

```
'payment_type' : lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0]
```

All together in sample:

```
chunk = pd.DataFrame({'msno':list('aaaddd'),
                   'late_count':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'is_discount':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'is_not_discount':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'discount':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'is_auto_renew':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'is_cancel':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'payment_type':[1,0,0,1,1,0]})

print (chunk)
   discount  is_auto_renew  is_cancel  is_discount  is_not_discount  \
0         7              1          5            7                4   
1         8              3          3            8                5   
2         9              5          6            9                4   
3         4              7          9            4                5   
4         2              1          2            2                5   
5         3              0          4            3                4   

   late_count msno  payment_type  
0           4    a             1  
1           5    a             0  
2           4    a             0  
3           5    d             1  
4           5    d             1  
5           4    d             0
```

---

```
grouped_object=chunk.groupby('msno',sort=False)
func = {
        'late_count':['sum'],
        'is_discount':['count'],
        'is_not_discount':['count'],
        'discount':['sum'], 
        'is_auto_renew':['mean'], 
        'is_cancel':['mean'], 
        'payment_type' : [lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0]]}
result=grouped_object.agg(func)
print (result)

     is_not_discount is_discount is_cancel discount late_count is_auto_renew  \
               count       count      mean      sum        sum          mean   
msno                                                                           
a                  3           3  4.666667       24         13      3.000000   
d                  3           3  5.000000        9         14      2.666667   

     payment_type  
         <lambda>  
msno               
a               0  
d               1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`series.mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mode.html) i.e

```
func = {
        'late_count':['sum'],
        'is_discount':['count'],
        'is_not_discount':['count'],
        'discount':['sum'], 'is_auto_renew':['mean'], 'is_cancel':['mean'],
        'payment_type': lambda x : x.mode()}
# Data from @ jezrael. 

grouped_object.agg(func).rename(columns={'<lambda>': 'mode'})
```

Output :

```
is_not_discount is_auto_renew late_count payment_type discount  \
               count          mean        sum         mode      sum   
msno                                                                  
a                  3      3.000000         13            0       24   
d                  3      2.666667         14            1        9   

     is_discount is_cancel  
           count      mean  
msno                        
a              3  4.666667  
d              3  5.000000
```

Comment: Not sure, but it retunr only one value? Check last sentence of question.

Comment: Oh I missed it : (.